# problems first row xml

Tags: c#, xml, html-agility-pack

I have this xml file which doesn't show any content depending on that the first row has 3 invisible bytes on xml version, see:

http://mark.koli.ch/resolving-orgxmlsaxsaxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

i tried this with agility pack c# but it doesn't work:

**Anyone knowing how to fix the file so web browser can read it?**

```
   try
            {
                HtmlNode xmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//<?xml"); 
                xmlNode.InnerHtml.Replace("^([\\W]+)<", "<");
                xmlNode.InnerHtml = htmlEncode(xmlNode.WriteContentTo());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<post>

<author>Admin</author>

<title>Njut</title>

<description/>

<content>Så står uterummet färdigt. Ett glastak över några stenplattor, eller glasväggar med plasttak uppsatta på ett trädäck. Det kanske är ett uterum utformat som en traditionell glasveranda från förra sekelskiftet, komplett med målade fönster och snickarglädje. Uterummet blir det som binder samman huset med trädgården och ger hemmet den där extra trevnaden som förgyller såväl sommaren som vintern. Vi talar om den långa ljumma sommarkvällen med den sjunkande solen i väster i goda vänners sällskap. Den svenska sommaren är en underbar men lite opålitlig vän, inte sällan täcks himlen av moln, ibland faller ett strilande regn men under det skyddande taket och innanför de glastäckta väggarna kan man ändå njuta av sommarvärmen. Vem vet, kanske ditt uterum blir det som räddar sommaren, även om det mesta regnar bort, som den kända sången säger. <img alt="Njut i ditt uterum" src="/image.axd?picture=matsrosen3stor-300x225.jpg" width="300" height="225"/>Helt klart kommer denna charmiga tillbyggnad garantera att din sommar blir lite mysigare och lite skönare. Solen fortsätter som bekant att skina även när sommaren går mot sitt slut och sedan övergår i höst, lite beroende på vilken form av rutor du valt så fortsätter uterummet att alstra värme och den sköna känslan stannar kvar långt efter att temperaturen utanför sjunkit och höstkläderna tagits fram. Sedan, när vintern kommit och snön ligger vit utanför kan julgranen ställas upp i uterummet och julens alla ljus och all dess värme skiner ut i ett gnistrande vinterlandskap med bara iskristallskimrande glasväggar emellan. Uterummet kan bli den oas där värme alstras, såväl solens som den mänskliga. En plats för stillhet eller en plats för fest. Uterummet är platsen där dina drömmar blir verklighet. Platsen att njuta av vid såväl alla livets högtider som i den stilla vardagen. En plats där man samlar de nära och kära men också får en stilla stund i ensamhet. Drömmarna finns där. Dags att förverkliga dem.</content>

<ispublished>True</ispublished>

<iscommentsenabled>True</iscommentsenabled>

<pubdate>2013-04-22 11:35:14</pubdate>

<lastmodified>2013-04-22 11:35:14</lastmodified>

<raters>0</raters>

<rating>0</rating>

<slug>8-revision-7</slug>

<tags/>

<comments/>

<categories/>

<notifications/>

</post>
```

Answer (score 0):

I once hat a problem with invisible characters at the beginning of a file due to a wrong encoding. Try using Notepad++ to open the file, then change the encoding (from the Menu-Bar). I gess the correct one was "UTF-8 without BOM".

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526466/notepad-convert-to-utf-8-multiple-files) post is about how to convert multiple files with Notepad++ using a little python script.